# Not displaying Location in GPU checked emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps, locationmanager

I have checked HOST GPU in emulator and trying to get current location but not getting anything neither error nor result.

here is my code.

```
package com.example.locationawareapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView currentloc;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        currentloc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CurrentLocation);

        // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
              // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
              makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
            }
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
          };

        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }

    protected void makeUseOfNewLocation(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        currentloc.setText(new Double(location.getLatitude()).toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

can anyone help to get this. I have already checked with some of existing questions but problem not resolved.

Regards,
Sourabh

Comment: How are you giving locations to the emulator? DDMS? `geo` commands in the emulator console?

Comment: I don't know about this. only the above code I am trying to run.

Comment: There are many Android developer support sites on the Internet, offering help in many languages. I have several sites listed at http://www.andglobe.com. You will have better luck using a site that is in a language that is more comfortable for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer :

let me share my understanding to explain that what is happening and what we need to do and why.

Emulator donot have any inbuild GPS hardware that it can use but the LocationManager class and its method implementation is going to perform there task when they recieve Location information. as emulator donot have hardware in-build we have to provide Lat Lon to application running on Emulator. to provide Location information we can use below Command Line

```
telnet localhost 5554 
geo fix <longitude value> <latitude value>
```

there is also simple way that I used, is using eclipse UI i.e. plug DDMS function to send GPS.
In eclipse go to window > Open Perspective > DDMS.
In DDMS you'll find the picture as below shown
[image: Screenshot of DDMS for GPS]

First go in DDMS section in your eclipse Than open emulator Control .... Go To Manual Section set lat and long and then press Send Button.

hope this will help you.